# Debian Live USB error. Help?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer

So I have a laptop (Dell G3 3779) with Windows 10 and Pop OS installed (both are on seperate hard drives). Recently, I installed some Dell UEFI Firmware update though Windows 10 and everything was working fine. Both Windows and Pop OS booted normally.

I wanted to delete my Pop OS installation and replace it with Debian 11, so I downloaded one of the nonfree (unofficial) ISOs and burned it to a flash drive. However, when I entered my boot menu to boot from that live USB, it goes to a black screen with the following error message:

**set_second_stage() failed: Invalid parameter Something has gone seriously wrong: shim_init() failed: Invalid parameter**

Then it shuts off. I don't know why this happened, as I've installed Debian and booted from USB before, so maybe the firmware update did something? Secure Boot is Disabled, so I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I've also tried installing other Debian ISOs like the live install version (nonfree) but the same thing happens.

How do I fix this?

Comment: the description of the problem os somewhat unclear ... the problem appears to be `unable to boot non-free distribution from a flash drive` .... try using a different flash drive

Comment: It could be you're having a firmware problem. The firmware is either free or nonfree - the distribution is free. The firrmware - whether free or non-free - can be installed later. Try a different image - or try the lastest Debian 10 (buster) image and then upgrade to bullseye using apt if it installs?